# How to get coefficient tables from multiple regression model result!

Tags: r, linear-regression

I've done multiple regression modeling in R using the below script. Now I'm wondering how can I make a table for the coefficients of each model of all models from lm, glm, and rf separately.

```r
all_variables <- names(PaC09c_w20_dat3)
response_variables <- all_variables[c(1:3)]
predictors <- all_variables[-c(1:3)]

lm_model <- lapply(
  response_variables,
  function(x) lm(reformulate(termlabels = predictors, response = x), data = PaC09c_w20_dat3)
) |>
  setNames(response_variables)

glm_model <- lapply(
  response_variables,
  function(x) glm(reformulate(termlabels = predictors, response = x), data = PaC09c_w20_dat3)
) |>
  setNames(response_variables)

rf_ranger <- lapply(
  response_variables,
  function(x) ranger(reformulate(termlabels = predictors, response = x), data = PaC09c_w20_dat3, importance="impurity")
) |>
  setNames(response_variables)

save.image(file="PaC09c_w20_Reg.RData")
```

Input data looks like (Original Table is very large),

```
  head(PaC09c_w20_dat3)
        EE87865ln1   EE87866ln1   EE87895ln1  blood_vessel_w20 adrenal_gland_w20 bone_element_w20 bronchus_w20 
               <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>         
        1    0.00391     0.00326    0.00332       0                 0                1            0             
        2    0.00139     0.00116    0.00132       0                 0                0            0             
        3    0.00360     0.00270    0.00469       1                 1                0            1             
        4    0.00323     0.00348    0.00339       0                 0                1            0             
        5    0.00323     0.00330    0.00382       0                 1                0            0             
        6    0.00278     0.00208    0.00214       0                 0                1            0
```

The expected output would look like this,

```
                           EE87865_lmcof   EE87866_lmcof
blood_vessel_w20           6.332633e-06    5.916615e-06
adrenal_gland_w20         -2.159470e-06   -2.399176e-06
bone_element_w20           8.578804e-06    8.106153e-06
bronchus_w20              -2.956291e-05   -2.152231e-05
```

Comment: Your code is neither reproducible (one would need the bed file) nor small enough to mentally compute what could be in each variable. How do you expect people on the forum to help you get to a random goal you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a solution,

```
 coefs_lm<-as.data.frame(lapply(lm_model,function(x)coef(x)[2:5]))

 coefs_glm<-as.data.frame(lapply(glm_model,function(x)coef(x)[2:5]))

var_imp <- function(object, ...) {
  var_imp_r <- object$variable.importance
  var_imp_r
}

coefs_rf<-as.data.frame(lapply(rf_ranger,function(x)var_imp(x)[1:4]))
```

`2:5` for `lm` and `glm` is the number of samples `EE..`, where 1 is intercept.

Comment: What is the `2:28` part? Is it specific to your dataset(s)?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `2:5` for this toy dataset in this example.

Answer (score 1):

To get the coefficients alone

```
lm_model$coefficients
glm_model$coefficients
```

Everything including coefficients its,

```
summary(lm_model)
summary(glm_model)
```

I assume this is the same for `summary(rf_ranger)`, albeit not sure whether `coefficients` would work here

Comment: `lm_model$coefficients` and `glm_model$coefficients` produces `NULL`. As you can see every model object (`lm_model`, `glm_model`, and `rf_ranger`) consists of multiple regression models of samples (e.g., `EE...`).

Comment: Given how OP has made these things lists, we'll probably need an `lapply` there.